# UCanAccess Print Statement?

Tags: ms-access, ucanaccess

Does UCanAccess include some sort of print statement?

I am currently getting some sql files from a third party source and then want to execute them. The statements themselves seem fine, but they used some `print 'xyz';` statements to monitor the progress.

I've never seen this syntax before and I cannot find anything on the web about it that seems to apply here. Is there some way you can get the server to execute a print statement that receives a String and then somehow forwards it to me using the JDBC connection with UCanAccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not, at least, according to the [docs](https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). `Print` is not listed, and not identified as a keyword.

Presumably, the SQL files are intended to be processed by a specific program that parses the statements, and doesn't pass these statements to UCanAccess but instead acts on them themselves.

This is not atypical, in the T-SQL world you can find many files with `GO` statements even though it's not valid T-SQL, just meant to be interpreted by SSMS and other programs running those queries.